# two player mobile touch issue in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a platformer game that has two playable characters. When the user clicks on the right side of the screen, the first character jumps and when the left side of the screen is clicked, the other character jumps. This is the code I have so far:

```
public enum WhichPlayer
{
   Player1,
   Player2
};

public WhichPlayer whichPlayer;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began && !IsDead)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        Vector2 position = touch.position;

        bool leftHalf = position.x <= Screen.width / 2;

        if (whichPlayer == WhichPlayer.Player1 && !leftHalf || whichPlayer == WhichPlayer.Player2 && leftHalf)
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("Jump", true);                
        }
     }  else
          {
           jump = false;
           animator.SetBool("Jump", false)
          }
```

The issue is that if I tap on the right side of the screen 5 times and then tap the left side 1 time, the   player on the right side jumps for 5 times and then the left player jumps once. Is there any way to make sure that the player jumps as soon as any side is tapped instead of waiting for all the other taps to complete. I tried using GetMouseButtonDown(0) and that didn't work properly on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to test this solution: (refactoring your solution)
you anlyse all touches and select the touches for each side..

i suppose you have a script for each player..

```
//Left player
void Update()
{
    var touched = Input.touches.Any(t => t.position.x <= Screen.width / 2 && t.phase == TouchPhase.Began);
    if (!isDead && touched)
    {
        //ok left player side 
    }


//Right player
void Update()
{
    var touched = Input.touches.Any(t => !(t.position.x <= Screen.width / 2) && t.phase == TouchPhase.Began);
    if (!isDead && touched)
    {
        //ok right player side 
    }
```

If you want the same script for all players, you could do that:

```
void Update()
{

    if(!isDead)
    {
        var touchedL = Input.touches.Any(t => t.position.x <= Screen.width / 2 && t.phase == TouchPhase.Began);
        var touchedR = Input.touches.Any(t => !(t.position.x <= Screen.width / 2) && t.phase == TouchPhase.Began);
        if (whichPlayer == WhichPlayer.Player2 && touchedL )
       {
          //ok left player side tapped
       }    

        if (whichPlayer == WhichPlayer.Player1 && touchedR )
       {
          //ok right player side tapped
       }    
    }
}
```

i give you the solution without linq :

```
var touched = Input.touches.Any(t => t.position.x <= Screen.width / 2 && t.phase == TouchPhase.Began);
```

could be replaced by:

```
    bool touched = false;
    foreach(var touch in Input.touches)
    {
       if(touch.position.x <= Screen.width / 2 && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
       {
            touched = true;
            break;
       }
    }
    if (!isDead && touched)
    {
        //ok left player side 
    }
```

same for other sample..

Comment: Its a better approach for sure. One side note to op is that you shall avoid LINQ in bigger projects for performance reasons, it's usually much faster to manually write your select logic

Comment: ok i note your remark! i write the same solution without linq. After the translation to no linq  code is not so complex, the idea is most important

Comment: @Frenchy , thanks for the help.....this is working fine now...